# Pushing data to array in mongodb document

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to push data to readBook array in my User collections document.
As seen in code bellow and console.log return both User is retrieved from db and there is data to push, however nothing is changed after code finishing to work. No error in console is shown. Please help!

I got a mongodb Schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "personal"
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    readBook: [{
        id: {
            type: String,
        },
       status: {
            type: String
        },
        rating : {
            type: String
        }
    }]

});
```

And trying to push data to it using express:

```
router.post("/ratebook", (req,res,next) => {
  User.findById(1)
  .exec( (error, user) => {
    if(error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      console.log(user);
      console.log(req.body);
      User.update( { _id: 1},  { $push: {"readBook": req.body}});      
    } 
  })
})
```

console.log return:

```
{ type: 'admin',
  readBook: [],
  _id: 1,
  email: ‘username@gmail.com',
  username: 'username',
  name: ’Name Surname',
  password: '$2a$10$JcuZNrjEh4KNOZ04TxIKLOy4/hcCK0It0.lAAE4zGN/qPavBFx8GS',
  __v: 0 }
{ id: '1', bookRating: '4’ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have console.log position above the update query, check the DB after the API call if the data is updated

or use following code and check console.log.

```
      router.post("/ratebook", (req,res,next) => {
        User.findById(1)
        .exec( (error, user) => {
          if(error) {
            return next(error);
          } else {
            console.log(user);
            console.log(req.body);
            User.update( { _id: 1},  { $push: {"readBook": req.body}}).exec( (errorU, updatedUser) => { 
            console.log("Update error", errorU);
            console.log("Updated User", updatedUser);
          });     
          } 
        })
      })
```

Comment: Update error null
Updated User { n: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  opTime: 
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1527151320 },
     t: 1 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001,
ok: 1 }

Comment: But still it does not update in db, and next time I execute code it still remains with empty readBook array

Comment: Can you check what is in your req.body? using console may be?

Comment: { id: '1', bookRating: '4’ } is req body

Comment: the keys in the re.body object should be same as your schema. say your req.body should be {
        id: 1,
       status: active,
        rating : 4
    }

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about that part, also forgot about adding .exec() into end of query